# What are some differences between Avicenna and Descartes in regards to being unable to doubt one's own existence

Tags: existence, descartes, avicenna

Given Descartes' Cogito and Avicenna's Floating Man arguments, what are some differences between them? It appears to me that they are both arriving to the same conclusion but the process by which they arrive to their conclusions is different.

Comment: The are quite similar; see [Floating man and Descartes's Cogito](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_man).

Comment: Also [Avicenna's Psychology](https://www.iep.utm.edu/avicenna/#H6).

Comment: One of these arguments was parodied by douglas adams in hhgttg, and the other wasn't :)